# Trynig to figure out why my Member Initializer list doesnt work

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class a
{
    public:
        a():a2(1),
            b2(2),
            c2(3)
        {
            cout <<"waruup\n";
        }
        ~a()
        {
            cout<<"Its over brah\n";
        }


        void kappa()
        {
            cout << a2 <<endl;
        }

        void kappa1()
        {
            cout << b2 <<endl;
        }

        void kappa2()
        {
            cout << c2 <<endl;
        }
};

main ()
{
a ao;
a *lol=&ao;
//ao.kappa();
lol->kappa();
lol->kappa1();
lol->kappa2();

}
```

why doesnt it run? I get an error at a():a2(1),
Am i getting soemething wrong? Isnt it suppose to make a2=1 and then print 1 when void kappa is called.Iam fairly new to programming and C++ in specific so excuse my nooby mistakes.

Comment: "I get an error" What error?

Comment: Where do you declare the class members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare the fields `a2`, `b2` and `c2` to initialize and use them.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class a
{
    // declaretion of fields
    int a2, b2, c2;

    public:
        a():a2(1),
            b2(2),
            c2(3)
        {
            cout <<"waruup\n";
        }
        ~a()
        {
            cout<<"Its over brah\n";
        }


        void kappa()
        {
            cout << a2 <<endl;
        }

        void kappa1()
        {
            cout << b2 <<endl;
        }

        void kappa2()
        {
            cout << c2 <<endl;
        }
};

// don't omit the return type of functions
int main ()
{
    a ao;
    a *lol=&ao;
    //ao.kappa();
    lol->kappa();
    lol->kappa1();
    lol->kappa2();

}
```

Also note that you mustn't omit return types of functions in C++.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how that should be done,iam not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Bathsheba [GCC said "field"](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OCNL6lFEoVRvm793), so I followed it.

Comment: Uugh! I've rolled back - I don't want to lock horns with those guys. UV'd the answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the answers,whats with all the dislikes though inst this website noob friendly?